# Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript

My code works with all the other modules but JBehaviour is giving me this problem and idk what im doing wrong because it seems like I did everything right

> Full Error: 
>   Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value # is not a constructor or null
>   at Object. (C:\Users\etern\Documents\GameEngine\src\engine\classes\JBehaviour.js:3)
>   at Object. (C:\Users\etern\Documents\GameEngine\src\engine\classes\JBehaviour.js:11)

**test_game.js**

```js
const {Vector2, GameObject, Rigidbody2d, JBehaviour, Input} = require('./Core')
```

**Core.js**

```js
//Structs
const Vector2 = require('./structs/Vector2')

//Classes
const GameObject = require('./classes/GameObject')
const Rigidbody2d = require('./classes/Rigidbody2d')
const JBehaviour = require('./classes/JBehaviour')
const Input = require('./classes/Input')


module.exports = {Vector2, GameObject, Rigidbody2d, JBehaviour, Input}
```

**JBehaviour.js**

```js
    const Behaviour = require('./Behaviour')

class JBehaviour extends Behaviour{
    constructor(){
        super('JBehaviour')
    }
}


module.exports = JBehaviour
```

**Behaviour.js**

```js
const Component = require('./Component')

class Behaviour extends Component{
    constructor(name){
        super(name)
        this.enabled = true
    }
}
```

**Component.js**

```js
const OBJ = require('./Object')
class Component extends OBJ {
    constructor(name){
        super(name)
        this.gameObject = null
        this.tag = null
        this.transform = null
    }

    AssignGameObject(gameObject){
        this.gameObject = gameObject
        this.tag = gameObject.tag
        this.transform = gameObject.transform
    }

    CompareTag(tag){

        return (this.tag === tag)
    }
}

module.exports = Component
```

**Object.js**

```js
class OBJ{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name
    }

    static Destroy(object){
        delete object.name
    }

    static Instantiate(original){

        return new OBJ(original.name)
    }

    ToString(){

        return toString(this.name)
    }
}

module.exports = OBJ
```

Comment: You haven't reassigned `module.exports` to be `Behaviour` class. By default it is an empty object. So you can't extend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't export `Behaviour`, so the value returned by `require('./Behaviour')` is an empty object. Empty objects can't be extended from.

Export `Behaviour` like you do with `JBehaviour`:

```
module.exports = Behaviour
```

Comment: im an idiot, thanks for catching that i now realize this was proabably for nothing but thank you